# How to assign an App Service system managed identity App Configuration Data Reader role for a specific App Configuration resource in ARM

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-app-configuration

I would like to add role assigment from my App Configuration to my App Service. In `Azure portal` i can do it like this: `App Configuration -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assigment -> App Configuration Data Reader -> Assign access to Managed identity -> Select Members (choose my app service) -> Save`
But now i want to do this through ARM template, currently I dont even know from where I should start, because in Microsoft ARM Docs i dont see something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.appconfiguration/configurationstores?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template

Comment: I will suggest to go for bicep instead of ARM template. Azure bicep is very concise, clean and user friendly as compared to ARM templates.

Answer (score 0):

First enable the system assigned identity in configuration stores resource:

```
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  }
```

Then better to declare a variable and get the **subscription resource id** by providing **role definition id** that you can find by going to **Add role assignment screen** in **IAM** for your app configuration service in **azure portal**:

[image]

```
"roleAppConfigDataReader": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', <Your role definition id for AppConfigDataReader>)]"
```

Then you will include it in the configuration stores resource's json:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
      "scope": "[format('Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/{0}', <YourConfigStoreName>)]",
      "name": "[guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', <YourAppServiceName>)), resourceId('Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores', <YourConfigStoreName>), variables('roleAppConfigDataReader'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('roleAppConfigDataReader')]",
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', <YourAppServiceName>), '2021-02-01', 'full').identity.principalId]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores', <YourConfigStoreName>)]"
      ]
    }
```

Please take help from the samples Microsoft provides from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?expanded=azure&products=azure-resource-manager

Comment: I got an error `{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'roleAppConfigDataReader' is not valid: The language expression 'subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions',id-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-xx-x- )' is not valid: the string character 'f' at position '72' is not expected.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'."}

Comment: There may be many moving parts here. So best bet is to follow the samples provided by Microsoft as well.